# Calculate the size of furniture which are available in the picture

Tags: furniture

Is there is any software which can calculate the size of furniture which are present on picture or image For Example I have an image of furniture I want to calculate its length, width , height size of that furniture is there is any approach or way ?

Comment: Are requests for software or APIs off-topic, as they are on the more technical SEs?

Comment: @jdv I'm torn on this, as it is a very woodworking-y question, but at the same time is not specific to woodworking. I think software reqs are mostly OK here, as they don't change nearly as often as in other fields.

Comment: I see your point. Maybe this should be a meta discussion. I think the reasoning is that such questions don't lead naturally to "one good answer". (Though, in this case, I think the answer is "no". So that's easy enough.)

Comment: @jdv, we've had software requests here previously (to generate plans, cut lists, related to CNC) so I see this Question as fine. However I do think the actual Answer is "No." as you say!

Comment: I think the main problem is that any recommendation and/or associated links in a Q&A will be outdated in an internet moment. And then this leads naturally to "Brouhaha WoodSoft 5 doesn't run on my Windows 11 box" and "Does anyone know where Brouhaha WoodSoft went?" sorts of questions. It sort of never ends, and is never fully complete...

Comment: @jdv, I don't see that as a problem necessarily, it doesn't invalidate the One Good Answer if it is somewhat time-limited. If we take a long enough world view there's a chance ALL current links might expire......

Comment: @Graphus this has been [much discussed elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297244/reevaluating-software-recommendation-questions), of course. I remain unconvinced WW.SE has needs much different than other SE. And give that we have https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, I'm not sure doing things different than other SEs is the way to go.

Comment: @jdv, I agree that doing things differently here would generally not be desirable. There are actually a few patterns here that don't follow common practice/protocol on other SEs and that should be curtailed, but it's neither busy enough or well frequented enough by our current mods to make this a practical reality (for the foreseeable future at least).

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is to compare the dimensions of the furniture in the photo to known dimensions of another object in the photo - a ruler would be ideal, of course, but anything of known size would work. Measure the size of the known object in the photo, and that gives you a scale - for example, 1" in the photo corresponds to 1 foot in the real world. You can then measure the size of the furniture in the photo and convert accordingly (e.g., if it's 5" long in the photo, then it'd be 5 feet long in the real world). Depth is tricky in this case, as it's scale can be different, so you'd want to calculate a scale for that separately - and try to get your reference object in the same plane of the picture as your furniture.

If you don't have an object of known size in the photo, you can hopefully use approximate sizes. For instance, there may be a person in the picture. You don't know the exact dimensions of the person, but you can estimate based on average sizes. Your calculated dimensions of the furniture will be estimates, but that may be better than nothing.

If all else fails, you can base it off of "standard" sizes for various items. Tables tend to be of a certain height (or range of heights), for instance, and bookcases tend to be within a range of depths.

Finally, consider if you actually need accurate dimensions from a photo. One of the great things about woodworking is the ability to build exactly what you need. It may be helpful to know that the table you're basing your design on is 42" square, but if you only have space for a 36" round table, then make your table 36" square. Some other dimensions may need to be adjusted to accommodate (e.g., apron lengths). Here some kind of modeling software (e.g., SketchUp) would be helpful to visualize proportions.